# Laravel - What is the proper way to use View::share?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I would like to define some variables, and maybe functions in BaseController, and have them accessible within my blade templates. I did some research and View::share came up.

I have the following within my BaseController

```
public function __construct() {
    View::share('local',"local");
}
```

At this point, what do I need to do so that I can access the variable $local, in my blade file (shop.blade.php) ???

I had tried just using $local, and I got "Undefined variable" error. I also tried using local() and I got "Call to undefined function" error.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am not using any other controllers cos I'm new to Laravel, so I'm trying out stuff little by little.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Are you very certain, that the constructor is called? Perhaps you're bypassing the controller and calling the view directly from the route?

Answer (score 2):

if i need to use `View::share()`, i generally put it in `global.php`.

simple example:

```
View::share('foo','bar');
```

in any view:

```
{{$foo}} //output: bar
```